# Unable to check the multi-select checkbox filter of the Kendo Grid Programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-multiselect

I am trying to programmatically check the checkboxes of the Kendo grid's multi-select checkbox and although this is a simple functionality of setting the attribute value of the input tag, it does not seem to work for me.

I have tried the following

```
1.<input type='checkbox' checked='checked'/>
2. <input type='checkbox' checked='true'/>
3. <input type='checkbox' checked/>
4. $(".k-multicheck-wrap >div >input").attr("checked", "checked");
5. $(".k-multicheck-wrap >div >input").attr("checked", "true");
```

None of these options seem to work inside the grid column's filter control. But if I create a checkbox outside of this control it does work

[Here is the code I am trying to work on](https://dojo.telerik.com/OqoCiNog/6)

Please help me fix this issue. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like that because in time, when you are trying to check those checkboxes - they don't exist yet. They are created after user click on filter icon.

From that reason, there is [filterMenuInit](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/filtermenuinit) event which is fired after filter is created. You can do your logic in there.

Note: That event will be fired always if user clicks on filter icon. It will be called only once - after initialization. And it will be called for each column where user opens filter options.

Here is a [demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OqoCiNog/9) how to use it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [ {
            field: "country",
            filterable: {
                multi:true,
                itemTemplate: function(e) {
                   
                      return "<div><input type='checkbox' data-text='#= data.country #' /><span>#= data.country|| data.all #</span></div>"
                    
                }
            }
        }],
        filterable: true,
        filterMenuInit: function(e){
          if(e.field == "country")
        {
            //$(".k-multicheck-wrap >div >input").prop("checked", true)
            $(".k-multicheck-wrap >div >input[type=checkbox][data-text='BG']").prop("checked", true)
        }
        },
      
        dataSource: [ { country: "BG" }, { country: "USA" } ]
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>
    
    <div id="grid"></div>
```